# Connection via Ethernet to Windows

Tags: ethernet, connection, ethernet-port

I'm having an issue with creating a direct connection with RPi 3 B+ and Windows laptop (to use as interface with RPi for first time set-up).

I formatted the microSD card to FAT32 (Master Boot Record) and added NOOBs. I was sure to open each folder and copy their contents onto the card.

Hardware info:

The power supply is a 5v 2.4amp cube.

The ethernet cable is a miscellaneous one that I found laying around.

The red led is stable and the green initiates a couple of times during power up then turns off.

The laptop is an older Lenovo with also an older version of Windows.

The physical connection is established (shown via the transmission lights on both the RPi and the laptop).

Interface info:

The ethernet connection is displayed under networks and I have the master settings set for sharing.

DHCP is enabled and it is given a both an Autoconfiguration IPv4 as well as an IP Subnet Mask.

Packets are sent from the laptop to the RPi yet none are received. This is also confirmed via the ping command in the Command Prompt (100% packet loss rate).

I've attempted to connect via PuTTY but the message, 'Network is Unreachable' is given. I presume this to be yet another verification of the lack of responsiveness of the RPi.

It is connected with the LAC2 and the connection stays stable (once again in the Networks section it confirms that there is 'No network access').

When I use the diagnostic function it says "'Local Area Connection 2' doesn't have a valid IP configuration    Not fixed"

I've looked over many tutorials (many of which presuppose that you have a connected RPi to communicate with, interestingly enough) and checked out some YouTube videos but all to no avail. Any sort of assistance here is greatly appreciated as I have so many ambitious projects in mind and being stuck in this most elementary stage is quite discouraging, to put it mildly.

Thank you!

Comment: `DHCP is enabled` - and you have a DHCP server? What you'll want to do is assign static IP's to both devices - a bit like [this answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/95419/can-i-connect-4-raspi-with-a-windows-pc-only-using-ethernet-cables-no-wifi-or-i)

Comment: "I formatted the microSD card to FAT32 (Master Boot Record) and added NOOBs. I was sure to open each folder and copy their contents onto the card." have you then booted the pi with a display attached and installed an OS? if you've just loaded noobs onto the card it might be waiting for you to install raspian which would explain why theres no connection because there's no OS to connect to.

Comment: Can you please execute this command on the Raspberry Pi on its command line:: `ip addr` and paste the result into your question? Please address me with @Ingo, otherwise I won't see your reply.

Answer (score 1):

> I formatted the microSD card to FAT32 (Master Boot Record) and added NOOBs. I was sure to open each folder and copy their contents onto the card.

This will not create a bootable SD card. You need to write the image to the card. This will create two partitions, a small FAT partition for the kernel and a larger Linux partition for the root file system.

On a Linux system, you would use `dd if=image-file of=/dev/sdb`, or `sdX` depending on where your SD card is. You can either boot a Linux live system, or use an equivalent Windows program.